# TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to tuple

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

I working on my BAC Project. I would like query time from my MySQL database. With this time which is my database, I would like compare it with the real time. I begin with Python language so...

[here it's my database][https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROxnQ.png]

Here is my code but I have an error "TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to tuple"

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import MySQLdb


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                    user="root",         # your username
                   passwd="Orel_27130",  # your password
                    db="projet")        # name of the data base




while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
    print (now)
    print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT time_open FROM time WHERE id = 2")
    time_open = cursor.fetchall()
    print time_open
    if time_open < now:
        print ("Fermee")
        GPIO.output(38, False)
        GPIO.output(40, True)
    else:
        print ("Ouvert")
        GPIO.output(38, True)
        GPIO.output(40, False)
```

Output:

```
((datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 23, 13, 0),),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 27, in <module>
    if time_open < now:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to tuple
```

Comment: what is print in "print time_open" statement? what is type of "time_open" variable?

Comment: print time_open is for me to see if the script query correctly the data.

Comment: `print (now)` is the same thing as `print now`; it'll print the *string representation* of the `datetime` object, which **may** look the same as the data returned from MySQL but that doesn't make it the *same type of object*.

Comment: Also, not sure why you use `print time.strftime()` there; that's going to be a *new* clock lookup, so it could be one second later already from the `now` result.

Comment: Could you include your table column definitions in your question? There seems to be some confusion as to what type of object the query returns for that one column. In your printed output we can clearly see a `datetime.datetime()` object, but in a comment on my answer the error suddenly changed to be about a `datetime.timedelta()` object. That doesn't quite fit.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve here? What kind of information is `time_open` recording?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are fetching *all rows* from the database. Those rows are stored in a tuple, and each row is a tuple of columns. If you wanted to compare the first (and only) column from a row, you need to *extract* that column:

```
time_open = cursor.fetchone()
if time_open[0] < now:
```

I used `cursor.fetchone()` to only fetch the first result row.

You also need to remove the `datetime.datetime.time()` call:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

You want the `datetime` object, *with* the date, because that's also the type of object that MySQL is returning.

Note that I'm assuming that `time_open[0]` is a `datetime.datetime` object. Your traceback was preceding by such an object, from the `print time_open` statement in your code:

```
((datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 23, 13, 0),),)
```

That's a tuple (rows) containing another tuple (one row with columns) containing a `datetime.datetime()` object. The MySQL database adapter (`MySQLdb`) created that object based on the column type as reported by the database; a column with the MySQL `DATETIME` type is converted to a `datetime` object here.

If instead you have a `TIME` column (which a new error message in the comments seems to suggest), then the value is converted to a `datetime.timedelta()` object instead, recording days and seconds of *time elapsed*. If you expected this to be a *time of day* instead, you need to either convert the timedelta to a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
if (midnight + time_now[0]) > now:
    # ...
```

*or* convert the `now` value to a timedelta relative to midnight:

```
# timedelta since midnight
midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
now_relative = datetime.datetime.now() - midnight

# ...
if time_now[0] < now_relative:
```

Comment: With your solution, i have this traceback


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 27, in <module>
    if time_open[0] < now:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to datetime.time

Comment: `time_open[0]` is `datetime.timedelta` type.

Comment: @abc: the printed output that they included with the traceback shows it is `datetime.datetime()` instead, not `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: Like this ? 
`if time_open[datetime.timedelta] < now:`
(Sorry i'm very noob :/)

Comment: @iDezwin: No, just use the code I posted in my answer. `time_open` is a tuple, `time_open[0]` indexes that tuple to get the first element (the result of `SELECT time_open ...` only has one column). Your `print` output shows that you had a tuple containing a tuple containing a `datetime.datetime` object, so you can compare that directly to the `now` object.

Comment: lets try according to @MartijnPieters

Comment: @iDezwin: I noticed that your `now` object isn't actually a `datetime.datetime` object, so I added advice about that too.

Comment: Thank you verryyyy much, this works veryy gooood !!! Thank you men, you safe my life !!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to convert that tupple to `datetime.datetime` format.

Comment: Gosh, really? And how would the OP do that?  This is about as useful an answer as 'Program it to work'.

Comment: Then it's like spoon-feeding. I just gave a hint which can solve the problem.

Comment: Where is anyone spoon-feeding? This *is* a question and answer site, trying to be helpful to all future visitors, so we do expect answers to be *helpful*. This one is not.

Comment: I just gave an idea. If you don't like it, you can kindly ignore ! Thanks :)

Comment: No, I voted instead, *and* left you feedback as to how I voted. That's the reason we have voting and comments. Don't tell people to 'ignore' bad answers please.

Comment: No problem. Dear !